# Fraction issue in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am facing a strange problem in crystal report 2008

I have a table (mytable) with two columns `col1` is `string` and `col2` is `float(15)`

Below are values in table

```
Col1       Col2
AA         5.82518987E-5
BB         5.88383009E-5
```

Created a report in crystal report and placed mytable values on report for `col1` it displays correct value but for COL2 it always displays FOR `AA "0.0000582519"` AND FOR `BB "0.0000588383"` instead of actual value in the table.

This is what in Crystal report instead of actual value.

```
Col1       Col2
AA        0.0000582519
BB        0.0000588383
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display the value in scientific notation?  Is Col2 being interpreted as a string?

Comment: Yes, It should display what ever the value is in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CR has the interesting limitation that the highest precision numeric value it can display is 10 decimal places (this includes trying to use the `totext()` function to cast the number to a string). This means that any float over that precision will be rounded at that tenth decimal.

Because of this and the fact that you're using a float which is precise up to 15 digits, the quick and dirty solution is to just manually convert to scientific notation by moving your decimal place over 5. You can accomplish this with something like:

`totext({table.numeric} * 10^5,10) & "E-5"`

Obviously, this will just indiscriminately convert all your numbers in Col2 to scientific notation whether they require it or not, so you may wish to add some additional conditional processing.

Note that if you Google "Crystal Reports scientific notation" you can find some custom functions to do that for you... but just be careful because a lot of these functions do not take the additional precision into account and WILL result in a much less precise number. In fact, the very first hit ([HOw to display Number in Scientific Notation  in version 2008](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1057248)) will chop that precision down to 10 digits in the very first line by using the `totext()` function.

Comment: Thanks it work.  I also find another way create an sql expression then cast field to text   CAST ("TableName"."Field" as varchar(20))